# How to create a slideshow with functions not images?

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet, slideshow

I am trying to create a slideshow function that adds and removes layers in my map through two buttons. This is an example of what I would like to do but instead of images, I want to the <   > buttons to add and remove the layers.
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow
The problem I am hitting is that I do not know how to add a layer to a map without creating a clickable button. I am using onclick, which is requiring the user to click on a button to use the function. I want the function to be called once the slideshow javascript gets to "mySlides" class. My HTML code below:

```
                 <div class="slideshow-container">
                    <div class="mySlides">
                        <input class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round" type="checkbox" onclick="toggleSewer();">
                        <label for="cmn-toggle-sewer">
                        </label>
                        <p class="child">Sewer</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mySlides">
                        <input id="cmn-toggle-water" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round" type="checkbox" onclick="toggleWater();">
                        <label for="cmn-toggle-water"></label>
                        <p class="child">Water</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mySlides">
                        <button1 class="fa fa-chevron-left" onclick="toggleOrtho();"></button1>
                        <p id="watermainLayer();">Ortho</p>
                    </div>
                    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
                    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
                </div>
```

After clicking "prev" or "next", a button is created. If I click the button, I do get the end result I want. Is there a way I can add sewer layers without adding the button in the process?